# What's the a good mailing list manager/platform?

Tags: mailing-list

I maintain a local Japanese conversation group and we're getting big enough that we need to get serious about a real mailing list.  What is a good solution?

Good means easy, free, low-maintenance... I'm currently on a mailing list (unrelated to the conversation group) that only admits plain text messages... I would prefer my mailing list to allow any type of email.  It would be nice if I didn't have to have a server to manage the list.  I would like to offer the ability to let the users read the emails individually or in digests.

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three offerings come to mind:

[MailMan](http://www.gnu.org/software/mailman/index.html) - this is Open Source and free. I think it does HTML emails as well and I know it does the digest emails if required. However, it's not a hosted option so unless you can find somewhere to host it for you, then this might not be the way forward.

[Google Groups](http://groups.google.com) is a second option which is free, hosted and does all the things above, but I don't know off the top of my head if you can send HTML emails with it easily.

[Yahoo Groups](http://groups.yahoo.com) is another one. As with the Google solution, it does everything but I don't know if it does HTML emails, so it might need some trial and error on your part.

Comment: Google Groups seems to work great for what I need right now.  Thanks.