# Best FREE Mailing List Manager on Shared Hosting

Tags: godaddy, shared-hosting, mailing-list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the a good mailing list manager/platform?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5852/whats-the-a-good-mailing-list-manager-platform)

What's the best FREE (**open-source**) (and/or easy to install) **Mailing List Manager** to be used on Godaddy's Shared Hosting (Linux - Deluxe 4GH)

I have no real preference when it comes to implementation language anything goes (PHP, python, or anything else).

Any experiences or "do"s and "don't"s?

**More Info**: 
I'm going to be using the mailing list as a way to promote my kart/auto/moto racing events to my costumers, probably 300...500 users.

I heard [phplist](http://www.phplist.com/) is good. Does anyone know if it's possible to install it on godaddy?

Comment: Mailchimp free for 2,000 subscribers. And you can send up to 12,000 emails per month. Definitely worth considering...

Comment: also, you can use feedburner to create a mailing list to create a mailing list from an rss feed.

Answer (score 0):

Mailchimp, everyday and twice on a sunday, it's so much easier to use than the competition it must make them cry when they look at their products. It's also free for the first 2000 users.